# Dual normal faces

Tags: normals, unity

I have created a model which requires some faces to be dual sided.

I intend to import this model into Unity. Reading about this, it seems that the recommendation is to duplicate the polygons and then flip the normals.

What I have done so far is simply to duplicate the all of the relevant faces using Shift+D and then flip the normals. I don't like this method though as it hampers any future alterations to the model itself.

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [*Solidify* modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html#solidify-modifier) to do this automatically.

You can control the distance between the actual faces and the flipped faces with the *Thickness*, and you can control which faces are doubled with a *Vertex group*.

If you don't want faces connecting the original faces the flipped faces, disable *Fill rim*.

---

You can have double sided faces in blender, but I'm not sure if they are faster than rendering extra flipped faces (or that they are even exported). The settings are in *Properties > Object Data > Normals*.