# Double Sided Faces

Tags: texturing, uv

How do I make the faces I am using for the leaves of the tree I am making double sided? Currently only one side appears, while looking at them from a different angle they disappear. The only solution I have read so far is to duplicate the face and then flip the normal so you essentially have two faces back to back, but I'd rather not do this because I am trying to keep my poly count low, these trees are for a game.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9049/dual-normal-faces

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### 2.8

In Blender 2.8 double sided normals are always-on by default, but if you want to turn them off (e.g. for export) you can enable *Backface Culling* in your material's settings:

[image: r 2]

Note that it's up to the exporter to respect this setting, so this may not work for every format/exporter.

### 2.7

For a game, I think that duplicating and flipping the normals is probably the best way to go.

Rendering double sided faces real-time can be very expensive, often more expensive than drawing the extra geometry.
Of course, it depends on the engine, so the best thing is to try it and see which works better.

---

Enable *Double sided* in *Properties > Object Data > Normals*:

[image]

Comment: Found this link http://www.katsbits.com/tutorials/blender/double-sided-faces-different-materials.php to describe how to flip normals

Comment: "Properties > Object Data > Normals" I can't find this...

Comment: @ThePoet I've added a screenshot

Comment: It's not there in blender 2.8

Comment: @MichaelCole Thanks for the heads up, I've updated my answer

Comment: @gandalf3 In 2.9 its now in Viewport Display > Settings :)

Comment: Changing around these settings does not affect the model once exported to FBX. How do I enable backface culling with FBX exporting?

Comment: @AaronFranke It is more of a render-time option, so you'll have to set it in the renderer you are viewing the exported model with. What are you using?

Answer (score 1):

For troubleshooting it is also helpful to toggle backface culling in viewport shading options here:[image]

This won't create any faces, but makes it easy to see where they are missing/flipped.

Answer (score 0):

Press E to stretch the selected in edit mode. Once stretched to the minimum amount possible select all faces and if there are any discrepancies press Ctrl + N to make Normals Consistent.

Comment: That's exactly what he *didn't* want for the sake of low poly.