# Why is my texture gray in the viewport?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv

[image: material settings]
[image: material settings]

I have an object which I unwrapped and already assigned a texture to it. I am trying to assign the same texture to the back of it, but I am getting a gray color on it. When I render it, it shows that spot black. I am using cycles.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and specify what render engine you are using, add  an image showing your material settings. It is hard to answer the question without seen what you have.

Comment: Most likely your object is perfectly thin because is made of one layer of faces (i.e  it's not solidified). As such it renders as black on other side because face has normal oriented only in one side; so Blender thinks that's the inner part of object and renders it in another way. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10711/double-sided-faces