# How do I make a plane with two sides

Tags: normals

I'm trying to make a plane that has two sides, or a plane that doesn't have a negative side. I don't exactly know how to explain it, but I want to have a plane where both sides are facing outwards. The normals should be pointing outwards on both sides of the plane. Thank you!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10711/double-sided-faces
Hope this helps you!

Comment: And seems like this option was in 2.79 but disappeared from 2.8+ and enabled by default.

Comment: How do I mark a solution? @AkaiShuichi answered my question sufficiently.

Comment: you can't mark for a comment, you can just mark if it was "Answered"

Comment: How?? I don't see a way to do it anywhere? There's no check mark?

Comment: I replied you in the form of "comment", unless I replied you in the form of "Answer" you can't Mark it, If I'm not wrong. Check this out https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers