# Is this is double-sided plane?

Tags: mesh

I have a hair object, and I wonder how it was done.

[image]

Is this hair composed by planes? 
And if yes, are they double-sided? To me it looks double-sided because it is also visible from the other side.

I have also uploaded the project [here](http://www.onscreensoftware.de/challengerhair.blend) if somebody needs to take a closer look.

Thank you very much!

Comment: yes it is made out of planes. Read [my answer here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/16609/2217) to see if it is double sided.

Comment: By default blender shows the backsides of single-sided faces. To make faces double sided, enable *Double Sided* in *Properties > Object Data* (see http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9049/599).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No they are not double sided. You can check this by going to the `N` menu and checking *Backface Culling* under *Shading* options.

[image: Backface Culling]

Comment: So you mean that these are just simple single-sided planes? You did not really refer to whether these are planes or not.

Comment: Yes, that is the default for Blender

Comment: @tmighty This question might help: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10711/double-sided-faces

Comment: Do you think you spot anything unusual with the planes or how they were created? I am asking because when I add a new plane and export my new mesh to a game engine (Unity in this case), this plane does not pick up a material and stays untextured while the other planes are textured.

Comment: Part of the same mesh?

Comment: Yes, they are part of the same mesh. I have even added some between the original planes to see if the location plays a role, but it does not. The only difference that I see is that my planes are quads, and the original planes are tris.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Planes are single-sided by default in Blender

Comment: I wanted to say that my planes have 4 edges, and the original ones have 3 edges.

Comment: That doesn't have an effect either. You have to manually make them double sided

Comment: Sorry I have not enough reputation for a chat, so I am asking here: You said that they are not double-sided, so I am a little confused why you talk about double-sided again. I have even converted them to tris using Ctrl+T, but that didn't make any difference either. Do you still have any idea why my planes would not take up a material? I am not sure what the difference between my planes and the original planes are. Do you still have any more idea?

Comment: @tmighty Do you not want them double sided? They aren't so if that is what you want you are good to go

Comment: Nope, I was just hoping you would spot anything unusual about the original planes.

Comment: Everything I see is completely normal :)

Comment: One last thing: In an fbx viewer, I can see that my new planes do not reflect the light as the original ones do: http://s23.postimg.org/vobzvc0qz/light1.jpg Isn't this weird?

Comment: Is the same material applied and are they UV unwrapped?

Comment: OMG, I love you!!! I forgot to unwrap it using "U"!! Thank you!!!